# prevent event bubling doesn't work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the DOM like this

```
<div class="modal">
<li>

<div id="block1"></div>
<div id="block2">

<div class="btn-wrap">
<button>cancel</button>
<button>save</button>
</div>

</div>

</li>
```

I have a click event attached to li and when I click button of block2, that event occurred. How to prevent that to happened?

I tried using on() but it doesn't work.

```
$('.btn-wrap').on('click','button:first-child',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('test');
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to prevent event bubbling:

```
$('.btn-wrap').on('click','button:first-child',function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   alert('test');
});
```

Comment: ah stopPropagation(), forgot bout this one! it worked thanks! btw if I don't use on(), I bind the click event directly and use stoPropagation, will it work?

Answer (score 1):

**Add** event.stopPropagation() to your handler

```
$('.btn-wrap').on('click', 'button:first-child', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    alert('test');
});
```